# In Excel VBA I'd like to change and delete some character from a type of IP format

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a task at work, that's about making an excel macro for some virtual servers, which can collect the right ip adresses into an other sheet.

So my problem is that the VM table's original ip format is like this host_192.168.1.39_32 and I need to change it to 192.168.1.39/32. This seems quite easy, but there are 6 kind of different formats, for example the ips are longer, isntead of 'host' there is 'net' and before the netmask there is '-' symbol.

I tried with the excel's own functions, RIGHT and LEFT, but for the 6 typle of formats I faild.

Can anyone help me with a scheme macro?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use `IF` statements in formulas to determine which of the 6 different types it is and then adjust accordingly. If you update the question with the an example of each type and what it needs to convert to you, we can help you more.

Comment: Hard to say if this will work without more sample data (can really only test against what you've provided), but perhaps try `=MID(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-2,1,"/"),MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&123456789)),LEN(A1))`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample (and inferred from your description) try,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(45), CHAR(95)), 1, FIND(CHAR(95), A2), ""), CHAR(95), CHAR(47))
```

That should cover at least one of your 5-7 format variations, perhaps more. More assistance can be forthcoming if you supply examples on non-working formats.

[image: ip_mask_parsing]